# Gridproblem. How to set 0 margin on the last child in each row

Tags: css, grid

So. I have a infinite grid with 4 boxes per row, where I want the last child to have a margin-right:0px;

Is there something like :last-child that could be applied to each last child of every row?

This is the html:

```
<ul class="grid">
<li class="feed-item">gridbox</li>
<li class="feed-item">gridbox</li>
<li class="feed-item">gridbox</li>
<li class="feed-item">gridbox</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there is a last-child selector. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alast-child)

Try:

```
.grid li:last-child
{
margin-right:0px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qT2N7/)

**UPDATE**

If you want to select every 4th child you dhould use [nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child)

```
.grid li:nth-child(4n)
{
margin-right:0px;
}
```

[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/qT2N7/3/)

Comment: better .grid > li or .grid .feed-item , to be sure not to override nested li

Comment: Works for me in chrome on jellybean...

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work for me. It does of course change the last child, but I dont have every row in a ul class. i have ONE ul class with an infinite (2000+) boxes in a 4 row horizontal column. I need every forth box, which is the last of every row, to have a margin-right:0px